# Scons doesn't use my environment variables such as PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: environment-variables, environment, scons

I have a little problem.

I source a script which changes my RedHat environment (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc.i).

When I launch my install with scons, it charges the default Environment from my machine, but not the current that I loaded...

I tried several attempts, but it was not conclusive. Most of the answer on the net are relative to a change on one variable which have to be set in the SConstruct.

How can I tell scons to charge the current Environment, but not the default ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCons way would be to set these environment variables in your SConstruct/SConscripts so that every user would end up with a reproducible build environment.

Take a read of the FAQ for this: http://scons.org/faq.html#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.

> SCons does not automatically propagate the external environment used to execute 'scons' to the commands used to build target files. This is so that builds will be guaranteed repeatable regardless of the environment variables set at the time scons is invoked. This also means that if the compiler or other commands that you want to use to build your target files are not in standard system locations, SCons will not find them unless you explicitly set the PATH to include those locations.

Comment: I understand the rationale, but this causes too much suffering on end users, because you have to patch the script to make SCons work on different distros (which have libs scattered in different places). The only way to have reproducible builds is Docker :-)

Comment: If the intent is for the build to propagate all or some of the shell environment variables, it can be propagated in the SConstruct/SConscripts. So as such, it's really the software developers choice what to do here. SCons doesn't force one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Already found the solution after some more search : env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)

Comment: Please be very careful with this code snippet.  It will eventually burn you if anyone else has to run your script, or you ever change your user environment.

Comment: This is in SCons's FAQ... http://scons.org/faq.html#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.